# How to copy file to folders and edit variable in file based on folder name

Tags: applescript

I have an .xml file that needs to be copied into every subfolder of a folder. There is a variable within that file that needs to be changed to reflect the name of the folder (without the path).

The code I have generates new folders within a selected master folder. It does this by getting the name of  files (ex .jpgs) within that folder, and creating new folders with the same name and putting each .jpg in its respective folder. I then now need it to edit a variable within the xml, which I have set up as "vID", and then copy it to each file.

```
tell application "Finder"


    set selected to selection
    set current_folder to item 1 of selected
    set mlist to every file of current_folder
    set theFile to choose file (* XML file with variable *)
    set MyFolder to current_folder

    repeat with this_file in mlist
        set cur_ext to name extension of this_file
        set new_name to text 1 thru -((length of cur_ext) + 2) of (name of this_file as text)

        set stringToFind to "vID"
        set stringToReplace to new_name
        set theContent to read theFile as «class utf8»
        set {oldTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, stringToFind}
        set ti to every text item of theContent
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to stringToReplace
        set newContent to ti as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldTID
        try
            set fd to open for access theFile with write permission
            set eof of fd to 0
            write newContent to fd as «class utf8»
            close access fd
        on error
            close access theFile
        end try

        set new_folder to make new folder with properties {name:new_name} at current_folder




        move this_file to new_folder

        duplicate MyFile to new_folder

    end repeat



end tell
```

Currently, the code correctly generates the folders, moves the .jpgs into their folders, edits the xml and duplicates it into each folder. The issue is that the variable is not reflective of each folder. It is just changed to the name of the last folder. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file is not getting updated because you overwrote the template, which replaced the placeholder string.  You can either make a copy of the template and then edit the copy, or just write the new XML contents directly:

```
global base_template -- this will be the master template to copy
set base_template to (choose file with prompt "Choose the template file:" of type "com.apple.property-list") -- XML file with placeholder text to replace

tell application "Finder"
  set current_folder to item 1 of (get selection)
  repeat with this_file in (get files of current_folder)
    set {file_name, file_extension} to my getNamePieces(this_file)
    set new_folder to make new folder with properties {name:file_name} at current_folder
    move this_file to new_folder
    set new_template to (new_folder as text) & (name of base_template)
    my copyTemplate(file_name, new_template)
  end repeat
end tell

to copyTemplate(name_text, new_template) -- write edited copy of template
  set placeholder_text to "vID"
  set base_content to read base_template as «class utf8»
  set {temp_TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, placeholder_text}
  set {item_list, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {text items of base_content, name_text}
  set {new_content, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {item_list as text, temp_TID}
  try
    set fd to (open for access file new_template with write permission)
    write new_content to fd as «class utf8»
    close access fd
  on error errmess -- oops, make sure file gets closed
    log errmess
    close access fd
  end try
end copyTemplate

to getNamePieces(file_item) -- get base file name and extension
  tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (file_item as text) to set {_name, _extension} to {name, name extension}
  if _extension is not "" then
    set _name to text 1 thru -((count _extension) + 2) of _name
    set _extension to "." & _extension
  end if
  return {_name, _extension}
end getNamePieces
```